# Properly load data from database into edit control so I can execute ADO query

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-access-2007, locale, ado

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I have an `MS Access 2007` database with a table that has `string` field and `numerical` one. The `numerical` field is of type `double` and can be negative or positive.

I use `ADO` to connect to the database and load its data into `edit` controls with `SetDialogItemText` API-`edit` controls are in the `dialog box`.

User can edit the values of existing data ( when saving changes I get data from `edit` controls with `GetDialogItemText` API ).

### PROBLEM:

Everything works fine in my program **if the user has English or US locale**, but if the user selects European locale then my `ADO` `string` is incorrect and reports error.

This is expected since in the English version it has 2 parameters-`string` and a `double` but since Europeans **use comma as a decimal point** ( for example US `123.456` is `123,456` ) `ADO` interprets it as having **3 parameters** instead of two-for example:

`INSERT INTO table VALUES ( 'some string', 12.5 );` ---> US locale

`INSERT INTO table VALUES ( 'some string', 12,5 );` ---> ERROR! 3 parameters instead 2

To explain more thoroughly:

Let us say that we have loaded data from database into edit controls using **European** locale:

First one holds `string` ( `Some string` ) and second one decimal number ( `123,456` ).

Let us say user changes the `string` value into `Some other string` and presses the *Save* button.

Now my code gets values from `edit` controls but the error must occur since I got `123,456` from the second edit control ( **remember, user left decimal data unchanged** ), and my `ADO string` is not properly configured since now it looks like this:

`INSERT INTO table VALUES ( 'Some other string', 123,456 );`-->ERROR! 3 parameters

### MY QUESTION:

If the user has set the European locale, is there a way to load **decimal** values from `MS Access 2007` database into edit control with comma **changed** into dot?

Or maybe I can somehow `subclass edit control` to change comma into dot?

User input can be limited to dot and letters by `sublclassing` the `edit` control so that is not the problem. I just want to load data from database properly, so my `ADO string` can be executed without error if user decides **not to edit decimal data** like in the example I described above.

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: My solution to similar issues has been to cache the current locale, switch the locale to your preferred type ("english"), format your ADO insertion query, then restore the original locale, all using setlocale(). This ensures you get a period instead of a comma in your query.

Comment: @user1793036: Your suggestion deserves attention. Thank you. Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues at play here. I will illustrate using two locales:

English (Canada) -- EN-CA: which uses `.` as the decimal separator
French (Canada) -- FR-CA: which uses `,` as the decimal separator

and tiny bits of VBScript code (as I don't have C++).

### Issue 1: Conversion of decimal numbers to/from locale-aware strings.

The VBScript

```vbs
x = 3/2
WScript.Echo x
```

displays `1.5` when the Windows locale is EN-CA, and it displays `1,5` when the Windows locale is FR-CA. That text is what you are seeing in your edit box.

Say the user leaves the string unchanged. Instead of trying to use the *string representation of the decimal number* you need to use a locale-aware method of converting the string back to an *actual decimal number*:

For EN-CA:

```vbs
x = CDbl("1.5") + 1
WScript.Echo x
```

displays `2.5` indicating that the string "1.5" was successfully converted to a `Double` before adding 1.

For FR-CA:

```vbs
x = CDbl("1,5") + 1
WScript.Echo x
```

displays `2,5` indicating that the string "1,5" was successfully converted to a `Double` before adding 1.

Summary: When you receive a text representation of a number from the user you need to convert (i.e., parse) that string to an actual numeric data type, and the parsing mechanism must be locale-aware.

### Issue 2: Storing the number in the database.

The problem here is that Access SQL is not locale-aware; it only "speaks" US English. So if you try and "glue together" a SQL command under FR-CA

```vbs
x = 3/2
sql = "INSERT INTO Table1 (DoubleField) VALUES (" & x & ")"
WScript.Echo sql
```

you get `INSERT INTO Table1 (DoubleField) VALUES (1,5)` and that fails, as you have discovered.

The solution here is to NOT "glue together" SQL commands (which is a Bad Thing anyway, because of SQL Injection vulnerabilities and other nuisances). Instead, use a *parameterized query*:

```vbs
Option Explicit
Dim con  ' ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd  ' ADODB.Command
Dim prm  ' ADODB.Parameter
Dim x
Const adDouble = 5
Const adParamInput = 1

' test data:
'     the following statement is valid when 
'         the Windows locale uses "," as the decimal separator
x = CDbl("1,5")

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open _
        "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" & _
        "Dbq=C:\__tmp\main.accdb;"
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1 (DoubleField) VALUES (?)"
Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("?", adDouble, adParamInput, , x)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm
cmd.Execute
Set prm = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, so far I have only upvoted your answer. I like your solution but have a little trouble to understand it ( I do not know `Visual Basic`, and `MS Access` was not thoroughly covered by my former professor ) so I might have have few follow up questions before I accept your answer. My first one is if `CDbl` is an `MS Access` function? Again I thank you very much. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Yes, `CDbl()` is a VBA/VBScript/Access function that converts a "thing" to a `Double`. (ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/type-conversion-functions-HA001229018.aspx))

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Further re: `CDbl()` - I only used that as part of my VBScript examples. You would need to use the corresponding mechanism in your C++ code. For example, if I was doing it in C# I would use something like `Convert.ToDouble`.

Comment: Is your variable `x` of type `double` or `float` or something else? I apologize but I do not know Visual Basic. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff `x` is a `Double`.

Comment: Being inexperienced, I have trouble with implementing the `Append` and `CreateParameter` mwthods in C++.I am studying the `ADO` documentation as I type this. Can I use `CDbl` in the above query like this `"INSERT INTO Table1 (DoubleField) VALUES ( CDbl( %s ) );` just so I can test your example? If your solution works that way I can always proceed trying to implement the methods I am struggling with to get the original version of your answer, yet if I get a problem than I could ask a follow up question and save time. Sorry for disturbance, but I am inexperienced. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Yes, imbedding the `CDbl()` into the SQL statement should be okay for proof-of-concept. However, it really is important to use a proper parameterized query for production code because you are receiving the string values from the user.

Comment: I have managed to convert your code into C++ with the help of `ADO` code examples from `MSDN` and a little thinking-everything works. Now I have to figure out how to convert `x = CDbl( " 1,5 " )` into C++ and I will be able to test your solution. Thanks for a swift reply. Best regards!

Comment: Just a few notes, so you can edit your answer so it can be helpful to future generations: I have used `_wsetlocale( LC_ALL, L"" );` to **load current local settings**. Then I have used the expression `_wtof_l( myStringVariable, _get_current_locale() )` to convert `string` to `double` properly. After transfering your code to C++ everything else seems to work. Again, the key was to load current local setting-you did not mentioned that. Thank you for your help-I have already upvoted your answer. Best regards.